# How to add values of colums in 2 data frames if first rows are identical?

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames with the same first columns identical.

```
df1 = data.frame(Probe = c(1:6), Date = c(rep("2016", 2), rep("2017", 2), rep("2018", 2)), Depth = c(rep("30", 3), rep("60", 3)), Insects = sample(1:10, 6, replace=FALSE), Komments = c(NA,NA, "Error",NA,NA,NA))
df2 = data.frame(Probe = c(1:6), Date = c(rep("2016", 2), rep("2017", 2), rep("2018", 2)), Depth = c(rep("30", 3), rep("60", 3)), Insects = sample(1:10, 6, replace=FALSE), Comments = c(NA,NA,"Error",NA,NA,"Error"))
```

I already found merge and left_join of dplyr, but I can't find a way to add the amount of the insects in df2 to df1 if the first 3 columns match. 
Additionally I would like to add the comments. In case of comments in both dataframes I would like to generate a "Error, Error" in row 3.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2,by=c('Probe','Date','Depth')) %>% 
        mutate(Comment=if_else(!is.na(Komments) & !is.na(Comments),paste0(Komments,',',Comments),NA_character_))
```